# Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a function that changes button text from `BOX NAME 1` to just `1` on a specific css media query. The function doesn't work because I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. That's one of my first jQuery functions ever written so I might have gotten my syntax messed up. Please help.

PS. I know that I've used `.text-boxes-button` class in my jQuery function that doesn't exist in my HTML, but it's just an extension from SASS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize(){
    if ($(".text-boxes-button").css("position") == "static" ){
        $("#button1").text("1");
        $("#button2").text("2");
        $("#button3").text("3");
        $("#button4").text("4");
    }
}
```

```css
.text-boxes-button {
    padding: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;

    a {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    @include mobile {
        position: static;
    }
}


#button1 {
    @extend .text-boxes-button;
    background-color: $button-blue;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#button2 {
    @extend .text-boxes-button;
    background-color: $button-red;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#button3 {
    @extend .text-boxes-button;
    background-color: $button-yellow;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#button4 {
    @extend .text-boxes-button;
    background-color: $button-green;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-buttons-wrapper">
  <div id="button1">
    <a href="#">Box name 1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="button2">
  <a href="#">Box name 2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="button3">
  <a href="#">Box name 3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="button4">
  <a href="#">Box name 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a `function()` inside `checkSize()`?

Comment: To be honest - I don't know. Tried with and without it and it doesn't work. Like I've said - I'm a total beginner and it's my first function so I'm not comfortable with syntax and all that stuff yet. @updated post to be without that function.

Comment: Are you really sure `.text-boxes-button` catches anything? What do you mean with "it's just an extension from SASS"? Could you please post your SASS code ?

Comment: edited first post snippet to include SASS.